# Gnuplot write caption next to datapoints from table

Tags: gnuplot

is there a way to caption datapoints with gnuplot? If not has anyone written a skript that does that automatically?

i want to have it like this :
http://d.imagehost.org/0343/Screenshot-Gnuplot_window_id_0.png

Only the 'Datapoint' should come from the same dataset as the values of the data.

cheers,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to plot your data the usually way and then plot datapoints captions with:

```
plot (...) with labels (...)
```

Look for detail in the [documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.2/gnuplot.html#x1-25600043.59.8.13)